# Android: Handling multiple EditText, updating them parallely

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi i have 3 edittexts when some enters the values in the 1st edittext parallel the other two edit texts will be update with converted values. same when i enter the values in other two edittexts  remaining edittexts will be updated , but the values are wrongly calculated since it is taking the values into consideration and updating .how to make focus on editext and consider only entered values but not the other calculated values .

```
edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    boolean editing = false;
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(!editing) 
        { 
        editing = true;
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
           edt2.setText(String.valueOf(hexTodecimal(qtyString)));
           edt3.setText(String.valueOf(hexTobinary(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt2.setText("");
           edt3.setText("");
        }
        editing = false;
        } 

    }
});
```

**my edittext 2**

```
edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    boolean editing = false;
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(!editing) 
        { 
        editing = true;
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(binarytohex(qtyString)));
           // edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTobinary(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            //edt_binary_val.setText("");
        } 
        editing = false;
        } 

    }
});
```

**my edittext 3**

```
edt3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    boolean editing = false;
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(!editing) 
        { 
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
           // edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(binarytohex(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            //edt_decimal_val.setText("");
        }
        editing = false;
        } 
    }
});
}
```

**Edit: I tried as below but the values are not updating**

```
textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {

    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        // System.out.println("printing sting==============="+qtyString);
          if (s == edt_hex_val.getEditableText()) {
            edt_decimal_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            edt_binary_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


              if(qtyString.length() > 0 ){

                    edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTodecimal(qtyString)));
                    edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTobinary(qtyString)));

                }else{

                     edt_decimal_val.setText("");
                     edt_binary_val.setText("");
                }


            } else if (s == edt_decimal_val.getEditableText()) {
                edt_hex_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                edt_binary_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                 if(qtyString.length() > 0){
                     edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTodecimal(qtyString)));
                     edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTobinary(qtyString)));
                 }else{

                    edt_hex_val.setText("");
                     edt_binary_val.setText("");
                }

            } else if (s == edt_binary_val.getEditableText()) {
                edt_hex_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                edt_decimal_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                 if(qtyString.length() > 0){
                     edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTodecimal(qtyString)));
                     edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexTobinary(qtyString)));
                 }else{

                    edt_hex_val.setText("");
                    edt_decimal_val.setText("");
                }

            } 

    } 
};
```

Comment: Instead of doing all in separate function create a common method with swicth case and pass the view within that method.
So that you can able to manage it better.

Also there is option to remove the TextWatcher when you are doing changes in 1st Textview remove the Textwatcher for all other Textviews.Now you can avoid this problem.

Comment: @Srinivasan hi i tried a common method, but the values are not updating...please look my edited question

Comment: `Edit: I tried as below but the values are not updating` 
  
i only see code that removes the textwatcher `edt_hex_val.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);` is there any code that add a textWatcher? `edt_hex_val.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean editing` should prevent recursive triggering of TextWatcher-events while setting the other  EditText-s. However since every TextWatcher has its own instance of `editing` this protection does not work. making `editing` more global should solve the issue.

```
private EditText edt1;
private EditText edt2;
boolean editing = false; // all EditText-s use the same editing flag

edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    // boolean editing = false; // make this global
    ....
});

edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    // boolean editing = false; // make this global
    ....
});
```

Comment: ...That's perfect...making boolean global works perfect. Thank you